# How to compute properties of a song like key, bpm?

Tags: signal-analysis, dft

How to compute the key and BPM of a piece of music? Is the Fourier transform necessary? I tried to approach this issue from the music theory angle and I found that I get stuck at trying to understand the terminology.

Comment: Man...  doing that kind of human perception modeling is tough.  I’d be curious to see if anyone has a response.  Suffice to say, our perception of sound is a type of frequency decomposition, which is in a very loose sense similar to the Fourier transform.  However, patern recognition in both the time and frequency domains would be important.  Not to mention, deciding on keys and tempos can be a subjective decision.

Comment: BPM is hard too?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how well you want it to work.  But yeah, I believe so.